# Gray body factors of PBH's - radial equation approximation (Page 1976)

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, kerr-metric

I'm deriving the results of the Page paper: "Particle emission rates from a black hole: Massless particles from an uncharged, nonrotating hole*" (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.13.198). At the appendix he derive the absorption probabilities $\Gamma$ given by equations (13) and (14) in the paper.
To that, he start with the radial Teukolsky equation in the kerr metric and Boyer-Lindquist coordinates for an uncharged hole, a massless field spin-weight $s$, frequency $\omega$, and axial quantum number $m$; given by:
\begin{align*}
    \Delta^{-s+1} \frac{d}{dr}\left(\Delta^{s+1}\frac{dR}{dr}\right)
    + [ 
    & (r^2 + a^2)\omega^2 - 4aMr\omega m + a^2m^2 + \\
    &+2ia(r - M)ms - 2iM(r^2 - a^2)\omega s + (2ir\omega s - \lambda)\Delta
    ] R = 0
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
   \Delta \equiv r^2 - 2 M r + a^2 
\end{align*}
then he do the following change of variables:
\begin{align*}
    x &\equiv \frac{r-r_{+}}{2(r_{+} - M)} = \frac{r - M - (M^2 - a^2)^{1/2}}{2(M^2 - a^2)^{1/2}}; \\
    Q &\equiv \frac{m\Omega - \omega}{2\kappa} = \frac{M r_{+}}{r_{+}-M}(m\Omega - \omega) = \frac{ma}{4M^2} - \frac{\omega}{2(M^2 - a^2)^{1/2}};\\
    k &= 2\omega (r_{+} - M) = 2\omega(M^2-a^2)^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
And, with that, using that $k\ll 1$, which implies $a^2\omega^2\ll 1 $, he arrives at:
\begin{align*}
x^2(x+1)^2 \frac{d^2R}{dx^2} + (s+1)x(x+1)(2x+1)\frac{dR}{dx} + 
[k^2 x^4 + 2 i k s x^3 - \lambda x(x+1) + isQ(2x+1) + Q^2]R = 0
\end{align*}

My question is specifically at the terms with Q.
I used mathematica to do the replacements: $/. r\rightarrow ((M^2 - a^2)^{1/2} (2x+1)+M)$ and $/. \omega \rightarrow k/(2*(M^2-a^2)^{1/2})$. Also, he divide the hole equation by $4(M^2 - a^2)$, so do I. The part with derivatives i got, but the term without the derivatives is more complicated. To simplify, I collect the powers of x of these part of the equation, which resulted in:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x \left(4 k^2 M \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-\frac{4 a^2 k^2 M}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+\frac{4 k^2 M^3}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}-4 a^2 k^2+4 i k s \left(M^2-a^2\right)+4 i a m s \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-4 \lambda  \left(M^2-a^2\right)-4 a k m M+8 k^2 M^2-4 i k M^2 s\right)}{4 \left(M^2-a^2\right)}+\frac{x^3 \left(8 k^2 \left(M^2-a^2\right)+8 k^2 M \sqrt{M^2-a^2}+8 i k s \left(M^2-a^2\right)\right)}{4 \left(M^2-a^2\right)}+\frac{x^2 \left(4 k^2 \left(M^2-a^2\right)+12 k^2 M \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-4 a^2 k^2+12 i k s \left(M^2-a^2\right)-4 \lambda  \left(M^2-a^2\right)+8 k^2 M^2\right)}{4 \left(M^2-a^2\right)}+\frac{-\frac{2 a^2 k^2 M^2}{M^2-a^2}-\frac{2 a^2 k^2 M}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+\frac{k^2 M^4}{M^2-a^2}+\frac{2 k^2 M^3}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}-\frac{2 a k m M^2}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+\frac{2 i a^2 k M s}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}-\frac{2 i k M^3 s}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+a^2 m^2+2 i a m s \sqrt{M^2-a^2}+\frac{a^4 k^2}{M^2-a^2}-2 a k m M+k^2 M^2-2 i k M^2 s}{4 \left(M^2-a^2\right)}+k^2 x^4
\end{align*}

The powers $x^4$ and $x^3$ are correct, and also the terms $-\lambda x(x+1)$, but i can't derive the $Q$ part.

I used mathematica to see the difference between what I was getting and the paper result. To that i defined the infernal term without $k^2 x^4+2 i k s x^3-\lambda x(x+1)$ as:
\begin{align*}
\text{Infernal}\text{:=}\frac{x \left(4 k^2 M \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-\frac{4 a^2 k^2 M}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+\frac{4 k^2 M^3}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}-4 a^2 k^2+4 i k s \left(M^2-a^2\right)+4 i a m s \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-4 \lambda  \left(M^2-a^2\right)-4 a k m M+8 k^2 M^2-4 i k M^2 s\right)}{4 \left(M^2-a^2\right)}+\frac{x^2 \left(4 k^2 \left(M^2-a^2\right)+12 k^2 M \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-4 a^2 k^2+12 i k s \left(M^2-a^2\right)-4 \lambda  \left(M^2-a^2\right)+8 k^2 M^2\right)}{4 \left(M^2-a^2\right)}+\frac{-\frac{2 a^2 k^2 M^2}{M^2-a^2}-\frac{2 a^2 k^2 M}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+\frac{k^2 M^4}{M^2-a^2}+\frac{2 k^2 M^3}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}-\frac{2 a k m M^2}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+\frac{2 i a^2 k M s}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}-\frac{2 i k M^3 s}{\sqrt{M^2-a^2}}+a^2 m^2+2 i a m s \sqrt{M^2-a^2}+\frac{a^4 k^2}{M^2-a^2}-2 a k m M+k^2 M^2-2 i k M^2 s}{4 \left(M^2-a^2\right)}-(-\lambda  (x+1) x)
\end{align*}
and the paper result as:
\begin{align*}
\text{NotSoInfernal}\text{:=}Q^2+i Q s (2 x+1)\text{/.}\, Q\to \frac{a m}{4 k M^2}-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{M^2-a^2}}
\end{align*}

And the difference that i obtained from Infernal $-$ NotSoInfernal was:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a^6 m^2+4 i a^5 k m M^2 s (2 x+1)+2 a^4 \left(m^2 M^2 \left(2 k^2 M^2-1\right)-2 k^3 M^4 \left(k \left(8 x^2+4 x+1\right)+4 i s x (3 x+1)\right)\right)+2 a k m M^4 \left(4 k^2 M^2 \left(\sqrt{M^2-a^2}+2 M x+M\right)-4 i k M^2 s (2 x+1) \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-\sqrt{M^2-a^2}+2 i M^2 (2 s x+s)\right)-k^2 M^6 \left(8 k^2 M \left(6 x^2+4 x+1\right) \left(\sqrt{M^2-a^2}+M\right)-8 i k M s \left(\sqrt{M^2-a^2}-6 M x^2+M\right)+4 i s (2 x+1) \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-1\right)+a^2 M^4 \left(4 k^4 M \left(2 \left(6 x^2+4 x+1\right) \sqrt{M^2-a^2}+M \left(20 x^2+12 x+3\right)\right)-8 i k^3 M s \left(\sqrt{M^2-a^2}-12 M x^2-2 M x+M\right)+k^2 \left(4 i s (2 x+1) \sqrt{M^2-a^2}-4 m^2 M^2-1\right)+m^2\right)+2 a^3 k m M^2 \left(4 i k M^2 s (2 x+1) \sqrt{M^2-a^2}+\sqrt{M^2-a^2}-4 k^2 M^3 (2 x+1)-4 i M^2 (2 s x+s)\right)}{16 k^2 M^4 \left(a^2-M^2\right)^2}
\end{align*}

even If i take the approximations $k\ll 1$ and $a^2\omega^2\ll 1$, the result is far from zero. I don't know what to do. Does anyone have any glimpse of what is going on?

Comment: Is there a difference between $\chi$ and $x$? Or between $\kappa$ and $k$? If not, why did you change the notation? And what are $a_*$ and $\Omega$?

Comment: @Ghoster Sorry, $\chi$ was the same as $x$, and $\kappa$ was the same as $k$. I just changed the notation for no reason. I've already corrected that. Also, $a_* = a/M$ and $\Omega = a/(4M^2)$. I've also added that to my question.